# Syntax highlighting color of #include statement

Tags: c++, visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

How to change the color of the thing that's inside `#include` statement?

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
```

How do I change the color of `iostream` and the `< >` brackets that surround it ?

Can't find it in the settings...

Thanks!

Comment: What IDE are you asking about? Never heard about any which supports *that* specific requirements.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017

Comment: don't think you can, they're just strings

Comment: Oh well... thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are just strings, so if you wanted to change that color, go to `Tools->Options->environment->Fonts and Colors`, then scroll down to `strings` and change that color:

[image: Here]